# BibTeX: "french" is not a string

Tags: bibtex, languages

I was trying to add french language support into gost-780 style.
I modified some functions (`bbl.vvolume`, `bbl.vvol`, `bbl.edition`) and now I am getting error:

> "french" is a string literal not an integer, for entry `guilcher_2003`.

I am not very familiar with BibTex syntax and so I ask ypur help.
Here is the links:
http://leftparagraphs.ru/lj/style.bst
http://leftparagraphs.ru/lj/french.bib

I can't post the third link to the `.tex` file (because of antispam filter). You need to add `\cite{guilcher_2003}` code.

Thanks for further help.

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe you are missing an `=` sign in one of the `curlanguage = "french"` lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in function `bbl.edition` (line 344) you have

```
curlanguage = "french"
```

but it should be:

```
curlanguage "french" =
```

It puts `curlanguage` and the string `french` on the stack and `=` compares these two values.

However, you have a lot of errors in your bibliography data file. You can find them with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\let\superscript\textsuperscript
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\nocite*
\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{french}

\end{document}
```

run this example file one time with `pdflatex` and then `bibtex` as long as `bibtex` reports an error in your bib file.